# CMIP6 Timeseries Values of 0 using ee.Reducer.mean

Tags: google-earth-engine, precipitation

I am trying to acquire long term precipitation data using the Nex-GDDP-CMIP6 datasets with the band "pr". I am able to create a time series, however, all the values are of 0 because they are being rounded down. How can I get around this because I want to know what the values are? The code I am using is below:

```
// Set years and month
var startYear = 2015;
var endYear = 2100;
var years = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);
// load the image collection
var GDDP_original = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GDDP-CMIP6")
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('model', 'CanESM5'))
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('scenario', 'ssp585'))
              .select('pr');

// make monthly averaged mosaics
// loop over the years and months to get averaged monthly images
var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(years.map(function(y){
 var yearCollection = GDDP_original.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'));
 var byYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
   months.map(function(m) {
      var avgImage = yearCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()); 
     var date = ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1).format("dd_mm_YYYY");
      return avgImage.set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1)).rename(date);
    }));
  return byYear;
  
})).flatten());
```

Comment: If I run your code and add `byMonth.first()` to the map, the results are not rounded down to zero. As explained in the [dataset documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_GDDP-CMIP6#bands), the maximum value for the `pr` band is ~0.008.